# Special Character in Export Variable

Tags: shell

I have a variable in my shell script that needs to declared as follows:

```
MY_VAR="/path/to/exec -options < inputfile"
```

This is the standard way the executable takes the input. Now, if I do $MY_VAR, the program quits with an error too many arguments. I suspect it is the < sign that is causing the problem. Any way I can get a workaround without splitting the statement into two variables?

Thanks

Comment: Are you taking the contents of the file as the arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval`, but that is considered harmful (see [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)). Try to find a better solution that does not need the whole command line in a variable. For example, use a function:

```
my_func() {
  /path/to/exec -options < inputFile
}
```

Comment: Thanks Philipp. I ended up having to split the MY_VAR and make it into two variables. The command line is part of the options specified by the user. The "<" was a special case.